# JS: Events and variables

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to raise event where some variable is changed?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observer for that variable that will be called whenever an action is made, and it will raise a specific event for that variable.