# Can JavaScript/jQuery make an element change automatically based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that's being changed all the time in the course of my application. Can I make an element change (contents, colour, whatever), when the variable changes?

Or do I have to change the element each time I change the variable. Ideally, the result would almost be like binding a change event to the variable...

Thanks

Gausie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here:
[Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Look at jQuery custom event support. It may not be a straight forward case in your particular usecase but you can use it to make it work. [Here](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/) is a decent tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a variable that's being changed
>   all the time in the course of my
>   application. Can I make an element
>   change (contents, colour, whatever),
>   when the variable changes?

Yes you can change, you know there will be the place where your variable changes, right? That's where you can change an element's content, style etc:

```
your_variable = 'this var changes here';
$('#your_div_id').css('color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a property on an object to store your value instead of a variable, you can add a [JavaScript watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Object:watch) to that property, and run a function of choice whenever the property is assigned to.