# jQuery trigger on variable change

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a setup where i load many modules as required, each module has a specific load needs when a specific variable is changed. I need something like jquery trigger but that runs when a variable change, something like this:

```
var x = 0; // no triggers

// something happens

x = 1; // will trigger a function
x = 2; // will trigger the same function
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can do exactly this...there's nothing you can listen to, can you give a bit more context?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript

Comment: that's a duplicate i'm closing it, thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could create an object that contains a `set_x` method to change the value of the variable. In addition to changing the variable, this method could call any associated triggers.

Then instead of setting `x` directly, you would use this new method:

```
my_obj.set_x( 2 ); // Will trigger a function
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
var x = {
    value: 10
}

var set = function(obj, new_value) {
    obj.value = new_value;
    /* call whatever your heart desires here */
}
```

So you can do:

```
set(x, 2);
// now x.value = 2
```