# Run javascript on JSON change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know enough jQuery/JavaScript to be dangerous.  I have a JSON array that I'm interacting with using two different elements (a calendar and a table, to be precise).  Is there an event handler (or any other way) I could bind to so that the table would refresh when the JSON changes?

Comment: If the JSON is in a variable check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267741/jquery-trigger-on-variable-change these are for triggering functino on a variable change. Make the function refresh the table.

Comment: Are you willing to use a javascript framewrok which is already avaialable ?

Comment: Thanks for the links, @AdamMerrifield!  I think I can find something in there.  I was trying to write my first jQuery plugin, so I'm not sure if using Knockout or another framework would work if I want it all to be self-contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic programming, parse the json (=string) into a javascript object or array. (you probably have already done that.) Use an implementation of the observer patern.

I suggest taking a good look at @Adam Merrifield 's interesting links.

Most of the time using getters and setter where you can fire a custom event (or call a callback method) inside a setter is the key in this.

[KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) is a good framework to help you do such binding. It also uses the observable - observer/subscriber pattern.

using timers is not a really good idea.. little to much overhead. (doing stuff also when nothing gets changed. And you will always hop x ms behind (depending on the polling frequency).

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll investigate Knockout.  I'm trying to make a jQuery plugin, so I wanted to keep it pure jQuery, but I'll see what I can do with the links that you guys gave me.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider Knockout.JS 
It allows bi-directional mapping, so a change to your model should reflect on your view and vice/versa.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

However, it might be late stages of your dev cycle, but something to consider.