# Userscript reload trigger

Tags: javascript, triggers, reload, userscripts

I'm writing a userscript for Chrome.

Userscript is written for a site that has special navigation. It sends a AJAX request, get data, and then do `location.reload(true);` so no `onreadystatechange/onload/onchange` or other events does occur.

How can I make trigger for location reload?

PS: No jQuery.

Comment: also, watch from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript for location.href does not work.

Comment: location.reload(true) just reloads the page right? so your user script should re-evaluated upon reload, is it not?