# "Bindable" variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data-binding

From my littleexperience in Flex, I learned about Bindable variables, so that the content of a text element changed with th value of a variable, for example.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do such a thing in JavaScript. For instance, suppose I have an `<h1 id="big_title">` that I want to contain the document's title. That can easily be done with `document.getElementById('big_title').innerHTML = document.title;`, but what if `document.title` changes? I'd have to manually update `big_title` as well.

Another way of putting it, is there a way to create a custom `onchange`-like event handler on a variable rather than a DOM element? This handler could update the title as needed.

EDIT: I know I could use a `setInterval` to check for variable "bindings" (defined in an array) and update as needed, but this would be somewhat hack-ish and would require a compromise between responsiveness and impact on performance.

Comment: Well you aren't really modifying a variable - you're altering the DOM. As far as I know, you can't bind a DOM element's text to a javascript variable. You could update it whenever javascript events are fired, though.

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I would rather have one single simple script rather than require a full framework for just one of its features.

Comment: You could always look at the source.

Comment: I did. Even with all the comments, I can't work out what does what and how to adapt it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "watch" objects in most major browsers. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript) is a shim. The idea essentially is to have a setter (in that example it's the function called `handler`) that will be executed when the value changes. I'm not sure what the extent of browser support is.

Although to be honest it sounds like a much easier solution to have your own setter method. Either make it into an object (you can easily extend this example to use a generic `handler` insetad of always changing the title):

```
function Watchable(val) { // non-prototypal modelling to ensure privacy
   this.set = function(v){
      document.title=val=v;
   };
   this.get = function(){return val;};
   this.set(val);
}

var title = new Watchable("original title");

title.get(); // "original title"
title.set("second title"); // "second title"
title.get(); // "second title"
```

Or if it isn't something you need to instantiate multiple times, a simple function + convention will do:

```
function changeVal(newVal) {
   variableToWatch = newVal;
   // change some DOM content
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Since I can only accept one answer, it'll be this one because it includes the single-function option.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to concentrate the related elements under one Javascript variable. This variable has a setter method and is bound to a user specified handler function that is called when the setter is invoked.

```
function Binder(handler) {
    this._value = 0; // will be set 
    this._handler = handler;
}
Binder.prototype.set = function(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this._handler(this);
};
Binder.prototype.get = function() {
    return this._value;
};
```

The Binder is used as follows:

```
<h1 id="h1">Title 0</h1>
<h2 id="h2">Title 0</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
function titleHandler(variable) {
    var val = variable.get();
    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = val;
    document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = "Sub" + val;
    document.title = val;
}
var title = new Binder(titleHandler);
title.set("Title 2");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way:

```js
 (function (win) {
   function bindCtrl(id, varName) {
     var c = win.document.getElementById(id);
     if (!varName) varName = id;
     if (c) {
       Object.defineProperty(win, varName, {
         get: function () { return c.innerHTML; },
         set: function (v) { c.innerHTML = v; }
       });
     }

     return c;
   }

   win.bindCtrl = bindCtrl;
})(this);

// Bind control "test" to "x" variable
bindCtrl('test', 'x');

// Change value
x = 'Bar (prev: ' + x + ')';
```

```html
<h1 id="test">Foo</h1>
```