# JQuery observable Listing control

Tags: jquery

Is there any free JQuery listing (you may call grid too) control which can be bind to an array as an observer such that whenever array data changes, listing control updates itself automatically eith array data?
thanks

Comment: I think you can look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the link.. but it still needs lot of programming... I remember of a jQuery control called something lite listing which had easy methods to bind to array, generate list and observe array for any change.. Couldn't find that control again..