# Call a function when variable changes

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some way to bind a function to variable change.

```
var arr = [],
    str = 'hello';
onChange(arr, console.log);
onChange(str, console.log);
arr.push('element');  // console output: ["element"]
str += ' stack over flow';  // console output: "hello stack overflow"
```

— or something like this.

Is there any kinda-mini-framework written in pure JS or with jQuery for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect variable change in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/detect-variable-change-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah, I need something like that, but also with ability to track array changes (via overwrited .push() and other methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) for this kind of ui element --> data binding. It's pretty awesome and supports jQuery by default (although other frameworks can also be used)

Comment: Yeah, I did consider using knockout.js before and wasn't sure if I want to rewrite a big part of my application right now. Now I found that ko.observable looks exactly what I want except for one thing: I'd prefer monkeypatching, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: And I initially thought that it requires jQuery Template :)