# How can I attach a change event handler to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

How can I track if this variable has changed?

```
var ConditionalFlag = 0;
```

I tried this:

```
var ConditionalFlag = 0;
$(ConditionalFlag).change(function () {
    alert("Changed");
});
ConditionalFlag++;
```

But to no avail. I have considered using a 25ms timer to check for change like this:

```
var ConditionalFlag = 0;
function CheckFlag() {
    if (ConditionalFlag > 0) {
        alert("Changed");
        clearInterval(check);
    }
}
var check = window.setInterval("CheckFlag()", 25);
ConditionalFlag++;
```

However, that seems like overkill. Is there a way to attach an event handler to this variable with jQuery or javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "event" that gets triggered when a variable changes.  JavaScript doesn't work that way.

When does this variable get changed?  Just add a call to a function after it does.

Comment: It gets changed as a result of multiple pieces falling into place. I suppose I could just set the pieces to be changed inside of a function which then calls the next function if all of the pieces are set - kind of like how teeth in a key lineup in a lock.

Comment: @TravisJ: That sounds like a better idea.  Personally, I feel that if you are "watching" a variable, you're not doing something quite right.

Answer (score 10):

If it's a global variable, you can use property accessors in supported environments...

```
window._conditional_flag = 0;
Object.defineProperty(window, "ConditionalFlag", {
    get: function() { return window._conditional_flag},
    set: function(v) { console.log("changed"); window._conditional_flag = v; }
});
```

Comment: I'm gonna assume this only works on modern web browsers (so not IE).

Comment: @Rocket: Works in IE9+ only. Older Firefox has the `__setter__` and `__getter__` properties. I believe FF4+ supports the standard accessors.

Comment: This is really cool!  I haven't messed with `get` and `set` in JavaScript before :-)

Comment: @Rocket: They are cool, but in my previous testing, they're also slow. I assume/hope they will eventually be optimized.