# Listening to a variable value change with getter and setter?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a function when the value of a variable changes. So far I am using `setInterval` for this but [that is not good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5282546/1010918).

Is `setInterval` actually used in production at all or is that bad practice? Will it fill up the page with events in the browser cache and make the page slower the longer a user is on it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282507/how-to-run-a-function-in-javascript-every-time-a-variable-changes) talks about getters and setters but unfortunately I have difficulties understanding how those work and would be super happy about a jsFiddle or an explanation for a JS beginner.

[This is](https://jsfiddle.net/rcck6vsq/) what I am using now. If you resize the executing window the event will also trigger so you can actually use this jsFiddle without zooming the viewport.

```
var currentZoom = screen.width / window.innerWidth;

function getZoomValue() {

var screenWidth = screen.width;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
// http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html
var zoomLevel = screenWidth / windowWidth;
    //console.log(zoomLevel);
    if (currentZoom != zoomLevel) {
        alert('zoom value/level changed to '+zoomLevel);
    }
currentZoom = zoomLevel;
}
getZoomValue();
setInterval(getZoomValue, 1000);
```

How can I use a getter and setter for this scenario please?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32754160/1010918) mentions using a global variable but there I do not understand how I can add the `zoomLevel` value to the global variable, plus using global variables is also bad practice, right?

Also, it says using [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) is not good, so I guess to really check cross-browser if a value of a variable has changed is to use a getter and setter, right?

I have checked and read through [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638769/in-javascript-how-to-trigger-event-when-a-variables-value-is-changed) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729598/how-can-i-attach-a-change-event-handler-to-a-variable) for research but I am still missing bits in my understanding. An explanatory answer with a possible jsFiddle would be highly appreciated.

**edit**
People are pointing out in the comments that I should check the `zoomLevel` on resize event and that it won't change its value. Unfortunately it will indeed change its value if the user [resizes the viewport](https://jsfiddle.net/uz12cg9n/).

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  var zoomLevel = screen.width / window.innerWidth;
  console.log(zoomLevel);
});
```

So if I attach the function to get the `zoomLevel` the resize event I will also get values despite real zooming is not happening. This is pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript#comment18150547_3596295).

Also Chrome and Firefox for Android do not fire resize events on zoom/pinch, only on orientation change, so getting the `zoomLevel` from the resize event also does not work in this scenario.

So how can I separate the window resize event results from the real zoom change event results and actually get the `zoomLevel` either with or without attaching it to the resize event?

Comment: Why don't you just use onresize event?

Comment: In this case, a getter/setter doesn't work because `screen.width` and `window.innerWidth` are never *set* like a normal variable; they are changed by the environment to reflect the size of the window/screen in a way that can't be detected by a setter function. That is, there isn't any code that ever does a set like `window.innerWidth = ....` As suggested above, `window.onresize` sounds like a reasonable option.

Comment: @dfsq The resize event also fires when scrolling on mobile devices (without zooming/pinch) so I cannot use it to check for pure zoom value change. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328742/mobile-chrome-fires-resize-event-on-scroll) & [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361968/javascript-resize-event-on-scroll-mobile).

Comment: Even if it fires on scroll, you can calculate zoomLevel, it will just not change.

Comment: @apsillers Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @dfsq zoomLevel will change on window resize as well as on zoom change. Like pointed out in the new edit I need to separate window resize events from true zoom events. So far I can only get this to work with polling the zoom instead of calling it on resize.

Comment: @dfsq Also zooming/pinching does not trigger the resize event on Chrome or Firefox for Android. Would be curious to hear if you have another idea of tackling this.