# JavaScript - how to detect a programmatic value change on a select element (dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript, I need to detect when the value of a certain select element has changed for *any* reason, *including* programmatically.

The onchange event is only fired when the user changes the selected value manually, *not* when other JavaScript changes the value programmatically.

This is a website with a variety of plugin components that we don't want to hack up (and in some cases *can't* hack up, since the code resides on other sites). **So triggering the change event myself whenever there is a programmatic change isn't an option.** I need to actually monitor the select, *listen* to it, for a change in value.

Is this possible?  I haven't found a way.

Is there perhaps some library I can use to frequently poll the value looking for change? Or some other way?

Comment: Trigger the `change` event when you programattically change the value. Something like `.val('something').change();`

Comment: Use the object.watch implementation from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 3):

```
var targetSelect = $('appropriate selector');
var lastVal = targetSelect.val();

setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = targetSelect.val();
    if(newVal !== lastVal) {
        // it changed, fire an event or process it
    }
    lastVal = newVal;
}, intervalSpacing);
```

The lower the value you pass to 'intervalSpacing' the more CPU time you spend, but the sooner you realize it changed.  Tune cautiously.

Comment: Oops; no it didn't work. For some reason, it is not detecting the programmatic changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MutationObservers API to watch for changes to the DOM:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

You might have to actually observe the `option` nodes for the selected attribute, instead of watching the parent `select` node, but it should be just as easy.

Comment: As I have discovered today, a Mutation is not triggered if the select's `value` property is written to directly.