# Detection of any variable changes after a function call, with debugger in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, developer-tools

Greetings I want to trace any variable changes that were caused from a specific function call.

My problem is that functionA has a specific behavior and after functionB is called the functionA behavior changes. 
So either of the following could help my situation:

- watch all the variables that are being changed by functionB
- watch all the variables of the functionA that are also used in
  functionB

If anyone could propose any appropriate tool it would be great.

PS I use watch expressions of Google debugger Tool but without result

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:
[Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

You can use [object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) but is not standard.

Check out Eli Grey own implementation:
[object-watch.js](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think that the object.watch is like the watch expression of the chrome debugger. In the sense that you should know which variable you want to see changes in. What I am looking for is searching for changes without knowing which variable I am looking for exactly. Thank you for your answer