# Execute special logic when JavaScript property is changed

Tags: javascript, properties

I have following code in JavaScript. I would like to execute some logic when any property in the object `sizeLogic` is changed. Specifically, I would like to change all other properties to false, when any one of these properties is set to true.

**Question**: How would I achieve this? I am not sure if this is even possible in JavaScript without writing methods like `set_leftTop(x)`, so that within the method we could write the custom logic.

```
var sizeLogic = {
     leftTop: true,
     leftBottom: false,
     rightTop: false,
     rightBottom: false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) useful depending on your browser support matrix.

From the MDN:

> Warning: Generally you should avoid using watch() and unwatch() when
>   possible. These two methods are implemented only in Gecko, and they're
>   intended primarily for debugging use. In addition, using watchpoints
>   has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true
>   when used on global objects, such as window. You can usually use
>   setters and getters or proxies instead

See: [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: Is this cross-browser compatible?

Comment: No. You may need to come up with a custom solution like shown in the linked SO post: https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

Comment: Ok. I hope I can use some cross-browser approach that is built-in for JavaScript.

Comment: I think its best to use methods for properties. So for leftTop, use set_leftTop and in the set method, all other properties can be set to false. This would work across all browsers.