# Skip loading html/javascript contents based on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

How would one go about conditionally loading html/javascript in the body based on a variable using javascript.

something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof variable1 === 'undefined') {
html elements and javascript functions/code here
}
variable1 = true;
</script>
```

one possible use is to avoid loading content more than once.

Comment: Since you don't have any Javascript variable setted at this point... No way to do it. But you could do this on server side.

Comment: in your example variable1 is always undefined so html elements and javascript that you want to conditionally show will always show/load.

Comment: Can you use angular?  `<div ng-if="!variable1">hello world</div>`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it should include on first appearance, when variable1 is not defined yet. server side not option. chaotic pages

Comment: @PeterDarmis that block may be added again so second time no.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK not an option. thnx

Comment: Could you show more code? I think everyone gets lost in "what we think you want to achieve".

Comment: First, why first load of the page is different from a second (like a refresh)? Can't you handle it from within this script?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can we call it a hypothetical situation? thnx

Comment: @Ray S.: I suppose yes. But It's getting harder to acuratly pin-out the bug. I' re-affirm that on EVERY page load, your javascript variables are unset (or undefined). Your question is then answered.

Comment: @RayS. yes you are right, second time it can't be undefined it is set true in 2 lines. Still you need server-side help for this or maybe something like localStorage.

Comment: Well... You may look at local storage... If this is want you want. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @PeterDarmis ok thanks. seems like such a simple task

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but you need a small piece of server-side work. You see in your example...

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof variable1 === 'undefined') {
html elements and javascript functions/code here
}
variable1 = true;
</script>
```

`variable1` is always undefined. So everything you want to ***hide*** by using that if statement will show/load. What you can do just before that is something like this...

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// try using localstorage
if (!localStorage.getItem("variable1")) {
html elements and javascript functions/code here
localStorage.setItem("variable1","loaded");
}
// later on you may have a function that removes the html and javascript that was added.
function foo() {
// function stuff
localStorage.removeItem("variable1"); // remove this so content may be able to load when needed.
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you please remove the down-vote since i am editing my answer @RayS.

Comment: Was my down vote... I removed it when you introduced local storage.

Comment: ok sorry @RayS. i thought it was you, logically down-votes go with comments .

Comment: localstorage does not clear unless you clear it by using `.removeItem()` or force clear by your browser's settings panel. @RayS. If you want to use it to store data and retrieve at any time then it will suit you in this.

Comment: how about document.write <!-- then after --> would that work?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the question correctly, You need to change the DOM based on a variable. One way to do this is to create an object and add a listener function that will detect changes in the object. Here is one of many posts that has a solution.

[Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

I have a fiddle forked from the one in the answer above. I have changed the fiddle to reflect changes in html based on the value of an object.

https://jsfiddle.net/140Lm69f/

```
x.registerListener(function(val) {
    document.getElementById('eventBased').innerHTML = "Someone changed the value of x.a to " + val;
  Console.log("Someone changed the value of x.a to " + val);
});
```