# Continuously monitor 3 text input fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to monitor 3 text input fields together. The following doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {                
    $("input:text").each( function () {  
        $(this).change( function () {
            checkinputs(this));                            
        });
    });
});
```

Some insight please. I want to check on each of the input field keyups whether ALL of them conform to standards enforced by `checkinputs()`.

In other words, when someone is typing in one of the fields, I want to monitor the current field and the other fields as well in real-time. This might not be as trivial as I think it is.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: it doesnt work. I cant pick up changes

Comment: Unless `checkinputs` returns a function that does something, it's not going to work

Comment: yea thas ficxed it.. I need to make another function to call it DUH trhanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kgtkd1to/

Comment: `this` in the handler refers to the element so you don't need to pass it to the handler. Also the `each` loop is not necessary. `keyup` itself iterates through the collection. `$("input:text").keyup(checkinputs);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: ok fixed my code. Stil does not pick up changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simplifying your code like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "input:text", function (e) {
    checkinputs(this); //
});

function checkinputs(input) {
    console.log(input.value) // <-- do something with the input
}
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgtkd1to/1/)

If that doesn't work, then you your problem is likely in the `checkinputs` function.

**Note 2:** You can bind to the nearest element that's already loaded on the page - `document` was used as an example.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check all inputs on input change, then the triggers remain the same however the `checkinginputs` function will have to take all inputs. Here's how you do that:

```
$(document).on("change", "input:text", function (e) {
    var $inputs = $("input:text");
    checkinputs($inputs);
});

function checkinputs($inputs) {
    $inputs.each(function () {
        console.log(this.value)
    });
}
```

**Demo:** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgtkd1to/2/)

Comment: I did try this earlier but what I wanted was that all 3 inputs are always monitored on keyup. But it turns out that it isnt easy to do that. Only the current text field will have its listener activated. I will have to nest the on change with a call to check the other two fields as well.

Comment: @asehgal I've updated the answer and the fiddle based on your comment.

Comment: it's super easy. see the update. You simply capture the list of inputs you need to read anytime a change happens, and then when a change happens, you read the values of all those inputs. Note how that phrasing, if there was no code, can be directly translated into working code.

Comment: yes thats what i was getting at. Just didnt know how to do it in JS. You have nested a loop over all 3 input fields inside each input change when detected at the DOM level. Thanks for your solution !