# Knockout - Computed Observable with manual Change notification

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

In knockout I want to write an ComputedObservable which is computed from values which are not observable. I want to manually trigger the Notification.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

A computed variable is nothing but a function that registers custom event on all observables inside it.

When ever your internal observable variable changes, it broadcasts a `notify` event and all listeners catches the event and process accordingly.

The process sounds simple but isn't when you plan to use on plain Javascript variable. You can refer [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery).

Now if you wish to achieve this manually, basic challenges:

- A variable can be changed anywhere, anytime. You will have to manually trigger their notify event everywhere. If you miss, you will have incorrect data.
- You will also have to add eventListeners for bindings. Like a `total` variable which should be computed.
- Browser support. IE8 or before does not support **custom events** and you will have to add hacks for it.

My suggestion, use computed (or pureComputed if on or above KO3.2) with observables. This way you will save a lot of code. Knockout team must have gone through these issues and have added handling for it in their code. You reinventing the wheel will add a lot of code in your codeBase and without proper documentation, will be difficult to maintain.

Following is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w5dh36jv/5/) where I replicated `textInput` binding for number input. If you see, they have separate handling of *IE10*, *IE9* and *IE8 or below*. They even have special handling for *safari below 5*.

Comment: I want to use knockout, and I want to use PureComputed. My only question is, hom can I raise a changed event, so all Controls bound to my PureComputed are refreshed? Because inside the pureComputed I do not use Observables

Comment: I already tried: 
         this.value.notifySubscribers("blabla")
where this.value is my pureComputed observable, but my UI gets not refreshed

Comment: Thats the point. If there is no observables inside computed function, there is no notify event and on change of these variable, computed will not be fired. So on `notifySubscribers`, subscribers will receive same value.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with the other answer on just using `ko.observable` variables in your computed. I don't see why you'd use a computed if its re-evaluation isn't automated. I'd advice to create a plain function instead.

The closest approach I'd see is to create a dummy observable that the computed subscribes to. You can call `valueHasMutated` to force re-evaluation:

```js
var a = "A";
var b = "B";

var subscriptionObs = ko.observable();

var ab = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  subscriptionObs();
  return a + b;
});

ko.applyBindings({ab: ab });


b = "C";
subscriptionObs.valueHasMutated();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="text: ab"></p>
```