# Log without erase

Tags: node.js

What's the best way to log a dynamic variable?

Example: while running the app, my log changes size and data. I want the log to not change, and simply save data.

This is my code for creating the log file:

```
const output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
const errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
const logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);
logger.log(res);
```

The var `res` changes during the execution of the app.

Comment: Your logging logs the variable at the moment you call `logger.log()`.  There is no automatic way to log every time the variable changes.

Comment: What's the purpose of the rest of your program? Perhaps we can help with your overall goal.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery for reference, I would suggest creating a function instead of the solution in the link though.

Comment: @jfriend00 my purpose is not log all variable changues in stdout.log and this file not changue never. This file should save all data of this variable.

Comment: Well, Javascript doesn't have that feature.  You need to log the value yourself after it changes.  Javascript doesn't have a feature to log it automatically after it changes.  Just isn't a feature of the language.  You could probably try to build one by proxying the object and overriding all properties with getters/setters or using some new ES6 features, but you'd have to do a bunch of coding yourself to capture all the changes to the object and to log those changes yourself.

Comment: I not explain correctly, what i need is log file not erase for my script. Only log data, but not delete info logged.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking.  I'm moving on to other questions where I can tell what the question means.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a couple ways of watching for variables changes: [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Doesn't look like you have shown all your code, since as far as I know there is no 'Console' constructor. There is a 'console' object rather (i.e. `console.log()`).

I have previously created a 'logger' object in my code so that I could change how I logged throughout my code base.

i.e.

```
var logger = {
  log: function(msg) {console.log(msg)}
}
```

(But note that you lose some functionality in this specific example)