# Output all JavaScript statements to console

Tags: javascript, debugging

If you type manually into chromes console each statement one by one you get an output.

How would I get the same output to the console by debugging code stepping through each of the following:

```
var foo = 10
foo * 2
foo * 20
```

without having to do

```
var foo = 10
console.log(foo * 2)
console.log(foo * 20)
```

It can be in browser, with browser extension or node.

EDIT 1______
I don't want to use watches either.

Comment: This isn't exactly as you are asking for, but you can "watch" a variable by simply console-ing it out after a certain interval as in this example (which uses a library to show the value on the screen): https://github.com/jonbri/ticker-log#execute-ad-hoc-testing-code-with-keyboard-macros

Comment: You can also use the (non-standard) `object.watch`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: What exactly do you need these outputs for? Why doesn't the standard debugger suffice your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it automatically.

You can add each expression as a "watch" expression in the Chrome debugger, which will show what the expression evaluates to as your step through the code.

You could create a logger that outputs to console in `dev` mode and outputs nothing in `prod` mode. I'm sure there is a good `npm` package for this already, but, it looks something like this:

```
var log = env === 'prod' ? function () {} : console.log;

var foo = 10
log(foo * 2);
log(foo * 20);

// dev
>> 20
>> 200
>>

// prod
>>
```

Comment: I was wanting to avoid any decoration, I don't want to use the watches in my case.