# How does Vue.js, React.js, Angular.js actually work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

This is some sort of question from curiossity.

The question is:

How does these Client-side frameworks work, let me explain.

I am working with javascript for more than 5 years. And I don't understand one thing. How do they know when the variable (for example `title`) variable value changes???.

I would do it like this:

```
function onTitleChange(title) { //do some stuff }
let title = "This is some title"
let lastTitle = title;
setInterval(() => {
    if(lastTitle !== title) {
        onTitleChange(title);
        lastTitle = title
    }
}, 10);
```

Is this how they all work? Is this how the Vue.js knows when the variable value changes? If not, what sort of magic do they use to know when a variable value changes??

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @JozefCipa and @gurghet is `object.watch()` supported in other browsers than mozilla firefox? Is it supported also in NodeJS?

Comment: @durisvk I'm afraid that `object.watch()` is only supported in Gecko browsers. But in NodeJS you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchjs

Comment: Well it's mostly done by Observers, observable pattern, check this gist https://gist.github.com/austinhyde/4321f22a476e1cbee65f

Comment: Also there is a cool talk by Evan You, vuejs creator, https://youtu.be/r4pNEdIt_l4

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna try to explain it in very simple words, step by step:

1. make a `<h2>Hi</h2>` element on a simple HTML page
2. open browser console and store DOM element in a variable:
   `var h2 = document.getElemntsByTagName('h2')[0];`
3. make two other variables first `var obj = {};` and second `var text = '';`

   **this is the part that you are looking for:**
4. instead of simply assigning `obj.text = text` we declare getter setter's for `obj.text` attribute so that whenever we set new value to `obj.text` the corresponding DOM element changes too.

   ```
   Object.defineProperty(obj, 'text', {
       get: function () {
           return text;
       },
       set: function (newvalue) {
           text = newvalue;
           h2.innerHTML = text;
       }
   });
   ```
5. now go on and change obj.text value : `obj.text = "Hello again"`

for more information check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) out.

all the codes available at : [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soorena/wkwxLywb/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, Angular for example uses [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js), I recommend you have a [read](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/dist/zone.js.d.ts) about it.

Comment: this is actually a well-documented library. And it has support for my favourite TypeScript :) .

Answer (score -1):

Little about React - its not actually listen to changes of the js objects, because of it only call `render` methods of components, if `shouldComponentUpdate()` (default it use reference equality of the component state) return `true`, and check if returned `VirtualDOM` is equal to the real DOM.

Because of it - its much more faster then Angular, which use many of listeners and equality checkers for watching updates.

Comment: @Dimitriy Kovalenko It's also that `React` has a `setState(state)` function which is easy to find out when it's fired. Other frameworks like `Vue.js` and `Knockout.js` do actually listen on variable change.