# How to refresh a javascript variable in relation of time without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript

In an unknown time the variable it deals with get a new value. I would like to refresh the output at the page withoout reloading it every 10 seconds.

How to? Please help.

Comment: Find the element, then use the `innerText` property to update the contents.

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/y30qo4qy/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval.

```
setInterval(function() {

}, 10*1000)
```

as said.

BUT... 
If the new value of the variable, has to do with time, you 'd better use a timestamp method too, instead of doing your calculations based on setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like setInterval, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
 setInterval(function() {
  //do what you need to with the variable here
 }, 10 * 1000); //since millseconds
```