# Is it possible to override certain Javascript commands?

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

If I created an object that has an array as an attribute, would it be possible to write a method in that object that would make it so that, after an instance is created, that hard-coded commands now acted differently?

For instance, if I defined a constructor:

```
function Bunny(){
       this.arr = [1,2,3];
       this.doSomething = function(){
         //  do something here
        } 
 }
```

and then created a new instance:

```
fluffy = new Bunny();
```

Would it be possible to write something in "this.doSomething" so that when I perform a predefined command, like:

```
fluffy.arr[0]=7;
```

that the resulting action (either in addition to or instead of changing the 0th entry of the array from 1 to 7) is that, say, an alert pops up that says, "Happy Easter!"?

Comment: [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @LincolnBergeson the answers to the  related question barely mention `Proxy` which is the correct way of doing this now.

Comment: @Alnitak is there no hope for getters and setters?

Comment: @LincolnBergeson AFAIK there's no way to implement access to (initially) undefined array index properties other than via `Proxy`.   Getters and setters only work for properties that you already know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to some degree. Enter: [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Proxies act as wrappers around objects and allow you to intercept certain events on that objects properties.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

// Wrap the array in a proxy
arr = new Proxy(arr, {
  get(target, name) {
    // Whenever the user accesses the ith element
    // alert, 'Happy Easter! i'
    alert(`Happy Easter! ${name}`);
    
    // Return the actual value
    return target[name];
  },
  
  // You can also target setters
  set(target, name, value) {
    // Whenever the user sets the ith element
    // alert, 'Merry Christmas! i'
    alert(`Merry Christmas! ${name}`);
    
    target[name] = value;
  }
});

// Can still set values since a setter wasn't set
arr[0] = 7;
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  Is it also possible to perform an action when the user accesses the ith element, to alert('Happy Easter!'+i)?

Comment: @bloomers Absolutely! I just updated my answer to show how you could do that.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks so much!