# Function Called But Not Evaluated After Changing variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I want to make a .on function but I'm having a problem. The below code calls the .on function but to do the alert, the variable ready has to be true. I don't want to call the .on function after the "ready = true". I hope you understand me. Thanks.

```
var test = {};
var ready = false;
test.on = function(argument, callback) {
    if (typeof argument !== "string" || "function" !== typeof callback) return;
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        if (argument === "hi" && ready) {
            callback("hi");
        }
    }
}
test.on("hi", function(a) {
    alert(a);
});
ready = true; // Now it should evaluate the above function
```

Comment: so you want to evaluate your function when ready is changed?

Comment: yes, when i change ready to true, as the function has already been called it should be evaluated

Comment: well something needs to watch for the ready variable to change.... and you are going to have to queue up the calls until that state happens.

Comment: then you need to create a listener to your variable and when changed call your function. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 0):

To make the alert be called before calling `ready = true` you'll need to change the boolean login of the `test.on` function.

If you remove the `&& ready`

```
test.on = function(argument, callback) {
    if (typeof argument !== "string" || "function" !== typeof callback) return;
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        if (argument === "hi") {
            callback("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you call `test.on(hi..` it'll now show the alert.

Comment: Technically this is correct, however the comments now show the question was about something totally different.

Comment: No you haven't understood me. I want to make it with the variable