# Listening to real variable changes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I hope not to bother anyone. I don't have enough reputation points to comment and ask directly in that beautiful suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403125/8261024 .

My additional question to that great solution is: what, if I want to detect only real changes? What I mean is: if the value of x.a changes, i will know. What, if the value of x.a was 42 and after the change it is 42 too, but I want only a real change of the value? I only want to know, if it changes to dolphin or fish or sth.

Maybe I am blind right know so I can't see the obvious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes shure, simply compare the new to the stored value:

```
var obj = (function(){
  let store = undefined;

  return {
   get value() {
     return store;
   },
   set value(v){
    if(v !== store){
      alert("changed");
      store = v;
    }
   },
  };
})();

obj.value = 10;//changed
obj.value = 10;
```

Comment: Let's say, I use this and my name for the object is infoText instead of obj and my code is
[code]
    var infoText = {
      aInternal: oldInfoText,
      aListener: function(val) {},
      set text(val) {
        this.aInternal = val;
        this.aListener(val);
      },
      get text() {
        return this.aInternal;
      },
      registerListener: function(listener) {
        this.aListener = listener;
      }
    }

    infoText.registerListener(function(val) {
            alert("Someone changed the value of infoText to " + val);
    });
[/code]

Comment: @ilafant please underatand the upper code. Its quite similar to yours and you will he able to change yours easily. Btw mys is better...

Comment: you're right. Thank you very much for your help. As I said: I was a little blind the other night.