# jQuery: How to return a value outside a function that contains the 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code currently `console.log`s the value of the variable `timestamp` when the document is ready. Is there a way of running this every time the variable `timestamp` is updated in the `.datepicker()` function without it being in the function itself?

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  var timestamp;
  $("#startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(e) {
      var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      timestamp = dateAsObject.getTime();
      console.log("user selected: " + timestamp);
      return timestamp;
    }
  });
  console.log("test: " + timestamp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  <label for="startDate">Select a date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate">
</form>
```

Comment: @JamesDouglas "urgent"? Nowhere did I say anything about "urgent". I said that I spent hours battling this issue and am still no closer to a solution. That's what I said. Has nothing to do with "urgent" whatsoever!

Comment: You can't access it until the event occurs. What are you trying to do outside the event callback?

Comment: @charlietfl I understand that much. But can't figure out the solution...

Comment: Solution to what? You haven't explained the higher level problem

Comment: @JamesDouglas OK, I removed the first line.

Comment: You can't access it there.... When your code is running, it will not wait for the date to be picked, therefore you get `undefined`. You need to specify the action in your event-handler, and let it call some function where you can have something happen.

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is explained in the code comments. (I thought putting it into the code comments would help making it clear)

Comment: @some thank you, I understood that part already, but still no closer to the actual solution.

Comment: No .... writing it in paragraph text makes it clear as well as searchable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: @JamesDouglas Thank you for updating my question text! I seems I have yet to learn to properly formulate my questions. Will take your edit as a template. Now looking into the thread you linked to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be misunderstanding what you're asking, but couldn't you just call the other function from within the `onSelect` event handler?

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL6r5bqe/) showing this in action, which I believe is doing what you need.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var timestamp;
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(e) { 
            var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( "getDate" ); 
            timestamp = dateAsObject.getTime(); 
            console.log("user selected: " + timestamp);
            otherFunction();
        }
    });

    function otherFunction() {
        console.log("test: " + timestamp);
    }
});
```

Comment: And get rid of `return` since there is nothing to return to

Comment: @snapjs No, I can't call it from within there. Because that other function is handled via a different jQuery plugin. (I had certainly tried that before)

Comment: Better to use `otherFunction(timestamp)` instead of using the semi-global `timestamp`. You can probably shorten that function to  `otherFunction($(this).datepicker( "getDate" ).getTime())`

Comment: @WebDevBooster so what's the other function that needs this timestamp?  Can't you just call *that* function?  I think we need a bit more info to help you out!

Comment: @snapjs I deliberately posted the question without that other function because I need to understand how to solve this issue in general. I need to know how to solve this issue whenever in comes up.