# do something if variable changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable button if user didnt add anything into global variable "code". I tryied indexOf() however it is reactive only once. Lets say if i have button that adds "z" into "code" global variable, it does not execute function inside indexOf("z"); Can anybody help?

```js
let code = "";

$(document).ready(() => {
      function codeCheck() {
        if (code = "") {
          console.log("nothing")
        } else if (code.indexOf("z")) {
          console.log("do semething")
        }
      }

      code = "z";
      codecheck();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How does `code` change?

Comment: You check conditions with `==` and not `=` in your if. You also shouldn't declar a function inside the onready

Comment: I "fixed" your snippet, please fix the syntax errors now.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy there's nothing inherently wrong with declaring a function within `document.ready`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh that I didn't know ^^ I always thought it was a bad idea

Comment: `codecheck();` is called yet you defined `code` **C** `heck()` go to https://jshint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function to check if your string contains a substring

```js
let code = "";

$(document).ready(() => {
  function codeCheck() {
    if (code == "") {
      console.log("nothing")
    } else if (code.includes("z")) {
      console.log("do something")
    }
  }

  code = "z";
  codeCheck();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare the value of your var in the if condition you have to use `==` or `===` operator. Your are using the assigment operator.

```
let code = "";

$(document).ready(() => {
    function codeCheck() {
        if (code === "") { // <--
            console.log("nothing")
        } else if (code.indexOf("z") > -1) {
            console.log("do semething")
        }
    }

    code = "z"; 
    codecheck();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to figure out how the value "code" is being updated.
If it's via a button, add an EventListener that calls the codeCheck method. In the following snippet I used a jQuery change function.

```js
let code = "";

$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#myCode").change( function(ev) {
     let newVal = ev.target.value; // this will contain the value in the textbox
     code = newVal;
     codeCheck();
  });
  function codeCheck() {
    if (code == "") {
      console.log("nothing")
    } else if (code.includes("z")) {
      console.log("do something")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myCode" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can then iterate over the above approach and add a button.

```
<button onClick="addZToMyCode()">Add Z</button>
//JS
function addZToMyCode() {
  code += "z";
  codeCheck();
}
```

AFAIK I don't think we can put an event listener to a variable in JS.
Edit: found [this answer on Stackoverflow that you might be interested in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript).

Comment: I'm here to learn as well, can I know why the answer was down-voted?