# Can't pass the value from child to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my page that opens a popup window.

```
<div class="container-content">
    <div id="VKauth">In order to leave comments, you have to authorize via VK and grant all permissions.</div><br />
    <div>
        <a href="/authvk"
            onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Redirecting to VK...', 'width=500, height=500')"
            target="_blank">
            <object data="/images/VKAuth.png" type="image/png" class="authvk">
                Authorize via VK
            </object>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

A popup window comes up with the authorization form in VK (social media website). If the users cancels authorization, VK redirects them to a PHP script on my website (inside the same popup window).

That script is as follows (I removed irrelevant logic):

```
echo "<script>parent.response = 'user_denied';</script>";
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

I suppose at this point, before closing the window, it must pass the variable `response` with the value `'user_denied'` to the parent window.

On the parent page (the same that has the button), I have a javascript as follows (uses a little of jquery):

```
response = {
  aInternal: 10,
  aListener: function(val) {},
  set a(val) {
    this.aInternal = val;
    this.aListener(val);
  },
  get a() {
    return this.aInternal;
  },
  registerListener: function(listener) {
    this.aListener = listener;
  }
}

response.registerListener(function(val) {
  if (response.a == 'user_denied') {
      console.log('response is', response.a);
      $("#VKauth").append('<div style="color: red;">You denied authorization! Comments are blocked!</div>');
  }
});
```

However, after my PHP script on the popup page finishes and, presumably, reports the variable `response` with the value `'user_denied'` to the parent window, nothing happens at all. Even no errors in the console.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403125/2418445) to listen for variable changes. What am I doing wrong? A lot, I suppose.

Comment: I don't see any PHP code anywhere.  We'll probably need to see that too.

Comment: Isn't it enough to know that it does `echo "<script>parent.response = 'user_denied';</script>";`? All other logic is completely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Is [that reading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) enlighting?

Comment: Why are you giving me this? It is possible to insert javascript in php pages using echo. And it works.

Comment: Can you show the button code and how that calls the PHP page?

Comment: I added more explanation. Please take a look.

Comment: Just as I thought, doesn't clear anything up, right?

Comment: I solved my issue by using cookies instead of this, but I would still appreciate pointing me to my errors. So the question remains relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data the parent window like `window.opener.response = 'user_denied';` for popups and `window.parent.response = 'user_denied';` for iframes. Now there is a `window.postMessage()` you can use for more secure data sharing between windows. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I changed `echo "<script>parent.response = 'user_denied';</script>";` to `echo "<script>window.opener.response = 'user_denied';</script>";`. Nothing has changed at all.

Comment: Changing the variable value  won't rerun your code. You need you use a function that does something on call. Ex: `window.opener.doSomething()`

Comment: So how do I make it pass the variable to the parent window? I only was able to find  `parent.var = 'value';`.