# fire event when property of a variable is changed

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a re-usable object that would contain multiple properties. I would like to fire an event within the object that will update some of its own properties when a specific property is changed through assignment. I have read something similar to this but what they used was an object. How can I achieve this?

My apologies if this is something basic but I don't really have a formal training is JavaScript or in-dept knowledge how JavaScript works.

also I would like to add that this is something that should work in IE11 and up.

I have tested the method from this but unfortunately I don't really understand how can I implement it on my case.

[Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

```
var test;

function myObject(){
  this.dataSource = null; 
  this.changeEvent = function(val){
    //do something inside
  }
}

test = new myObject();
test.dataSource = 'dataSource'; //trigger changeEvent() inside myObject
```

Comment: could you please provide more information? the js code you provided above should work. `//do something inside` you should add the properties that need to be changes in here. What is the object that needs to be changed?

Comment: @A.JAlhorr lets just say I would like to do a console log when dataSource is changed via assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I'll start from the method you've suggested and it seems you like that approach.

Sorry, if this seems obvious but better to explain!

Basically `watch` watches properties within your object (say datasource) and when a new value is assigned - fires the `callback` function. So, watch takes two params - what to watch, and what to do (when the property you are watching changes).

The caveat with this approach is it's a a non-standard and was not implemented by other browsers. Although, we can get a polyfill (which declares it if it does not exist).

https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

Warning from Mozilla's own docs:

> Deprecation warning: Do not use watch() and unwatch()! These two
>   methods were implemented only in Firefox prior to version 58, they're
>   deprecated and removed in Firefox 58+. In addition, using watchpoints
>   has a serious negative impact on performance, which is especially true
>   when used on global objects, such as window. You can usually use
>   setters and getters or proxies instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

So, to implement using a polyfil of watch (thank Eli Grey for the Polyfill)

First, register the polyfill (put it somewhere which will run before anything else in JS, or put it in a polyfill.js file and import it first on your HTML page!)

```
/*
 * object.watch polyfill
 *
 * 2012-04-03
 *
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 * Public Domain.
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
 */

// object.watch
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
          enumerable: false
        , configurable: true
        , writable: false
        , value: function (prop, handler) {
            var
              oldval = this[prop]
            , newval = oldval
            , getter = function () {
                return newval;
            }
            , setter = function (val) {
                oldval = newval;
                return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
            }
            ;

            if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                      get: getter
                    , set: setter
                    , enumerable: true
                    , configurable: true
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
          enumerable: false
        , configurable: true
        , writable: false
        , value: function (prop) {
            var val = this[prop];
            delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
            this[prop] = val;
        }
    });
}
```

Then, to use (using your example);

```
var test;

**function myObject(){
  this.dataSource = null; 
  this.changeEvent = function (id, oldval, newval) {
    console.log(id + ' changed from ' + oldval + ' to ' + newval);
    return newval;
 }
  this.watch('datasource', this.changeEvent);
}**

test = new myObject();
test.dataSource = 'dataSource'; //trigger changeEvent() inside myObject
```

However, I would look into Event Listeners and trigger events when objects change - but that solution should work for you, especially with `watch`

[Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

Comment: Absolutely splendid! it was a good thing our framework has polyfill and this definitely solved my problem! Thank you for giving me a clear and concise explanation!

Comment: @jamescastillo - no problem!

Comment: What about nested `test.dataSource.prop=true` ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the object, wrap it in a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, **assignment**, enumeration, function invocation, etc).

Implement a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) trap which performs the needed internal changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value of dataSource in local storage and then compare and check if it has been changed.

```
var test;
function myObject()
{
  this.dataSource = null; 
  this.changeEvent = function(val)
  {
    console.log("Value has been changed.");
  }
}
test = new myObject();
test.dataSource = 'dataSource';
console.log("Before change" + test.dataSource);
localStorage.setItem("dataSource", test.dataSource);
var newVal = "dtSrc";
test.dataSource = newVal;
var originalVal = localStorage.getItem("dataSource");
console.log("After change" + test.dataSource);
if(newVal == originalVal)
    console.log("Value has not changed.");
else
    test.changeEvent();
```

Let me know if it works for you. If not, let me know the expected output.

Comment: This will definitely work but as I've stated, I would like to trigger the event when 'dataSource' is changed

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use like :**

```
var myObject = {
    _dataSource: null,
    changeEvent : function(val){
        //do something inside
        alert(val);
    }
};
Object.defineProperty(myObject, "dataSource", {
    get: function(){
        return this._dataSource;
    }, 
    set: function(newValue){
        this._dataSource=newValue;
        this.changeEvent(this.dataSource);
    }
});

myObject.dataSource= "dataSource";
```

Comment: downside is, its not reusable.