# Change the content of a specified position with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I feel uncomfortable having to create elements scattered everywhere and change them one by one when variable is changed.

```html
    <div>
         <div class="element-1"></div>
         <div class="element-2"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var e1= "";
    var e2= "";

    SomeEvent.trigger(function(){
        e1= "this is content of element-1";
        e2= "this is content of element-2";
    });


    $("value of e1").change(function(){
        $(".element-1").html(e1);
    });
    $("value of e2").change(function(){
        $(".element-2").html(e2);
    });
    </script>
```

Can I do something like it only with `js` or `jQuery`?

```html
<div>
    {{e1}}
    {{e2}}
    {{e3}}
</div>
```

And `{{e?}}` is binding with `e?`. It show `e?`'s value and change everywhere `e?` changes. Thanks.

Comment: [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759987/2796249)

Comment: @AhedKabalan 
Thank you, but this is not the main problem. I want to replace the value at {{e?}} with the value of e? without adding any html elements around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) and place your `{{varibles}}` in the template then pass data to them.