# How to access a variable modified in an async function present in one .js file in another .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, scope

I have two files a.js and b.js. The first one runs an async function, which contains a variable that changes everytime something is modified. I want to access the same variable with the modified data in it on another .js file

```
// a.js

var nodes; // I have defined a global variable
async function createEditor(container) {
    ...
    async function compile() {
        await engine.abort();
        await engine.process(editor.toJSON());
        nodes = engine.process(editor.toJSON());
    }
}

export {nodes};
```

The second .js file contains: -

```
// b.js

import {nodes} from './a.js';

console.log(nodes) // Outputs Undefined
```

Comment: You're exporting the value of `nodes` before the async function completes (and changes that value)

Answer (score 0):

Why not inverse the logic?

On file A:

```js
import { log } from './b.js';

var nodes; // I have defined a global variable
async function createEditor(container) {
    ...
    async function compile() {
        await engine.abort();
        await engine.process(editor.toJSON());
        nodes = engine.process(editor.toJSON());

        log(b);
    }
}

export {nodes};
```

While in file B:

```js
function log(...arguments) {
  console.log(...arguments);
}

export { log };
```

Comment: Otherwise, there is this observer/subscriber pattern with getters and setters that was suggested in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403125/2356080 

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ll check that one out :)