# Run callback() only if the value "changed" instead of "set"

Tags: javascript, variables

Linked [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

I want to run `callback()` only if the value is changed instead of set.
If it is set to the same value as previous one, `callback()` is not fired.
If it is set to different value then previous one, it is changed and `callback()` is run.

How do I do this? I tried storing it in `prevVariable` and `currentVariable`, and comparing them with `if` statement. But I was wondering if there is a better JS feature that does what I want? The variable I am receiving is from external source that I cannot control and I am currently running it with `setTimeout` to get constant update of the `currentVariable`.

Comment: You haven't shown your code, but the general idea you describe seems reasonable. If you have to keep track of lots of them, use an object whose keys are the variable names.

Comment: @Karizma why did you delete your answer?