# How to create variables that hold variables

Tags: javascript

I think this is a simple one, and it may even have been asked previously, but I don't know what keywords to use to do a search.  I believe that variables are strings and can only be strings, so even my question is a poor one, but I want to figure out a good way to do some math.

We start with something simple, like:

```
var a=0, b=a+1
console.log(a,b) // yields 0,1
```

But I then want to be able to update `a` later in the code and have it automatically update `b`, so if later I set:

```
a=1
console.log(a,b) // now yields 1,2
```

The goal being the updated `b` without having to tell the code that `b=a+1` a second time (or hundreds of times, as this is a lot of math I am playing with).

Comment: Have you tried to check the value of b after changing a?

Comment: @Professorval it would be unchanged

Comment: @OP what you want is function, rather than variables. The other way is an object with getters.

Comment: You can consider using computed property.

Comment: there are several ways to do what you want in javascript. try searching for "reactive programming" or "proxy".

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for something resembling an Excel spreadsheet. You work with values (a) and formulae (b) that are updated "automatically".

Comment: I admit, I am a bit of an old timer.  Lots of new ideas being presented here, thanks.  I admit that Excel is more comfortable to me than javascript.  I learned javascript a decade ago and am still back there in my knowledge.

Comment: working with getters and setters can be interesting (complex but scalable solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate function that updates both variables. Then, whenever you want to modify them, call the method instead of reassigning the variables manually, for example:

```js
var a = 0,
  b = a + 1;

const increment = () => {
  a++;
  b++;
};
increment();
increment();
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: This ```const``` is new to me, but only because I have not kept up to date.  It appears to basically be a function, but one that cannot be changed/updated?

Comment: Yeah, I prefer using `const` to declare variables whenever possible, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6 - it makes code more readable at a glance when you can immediately determine whether something may possibly be reassigned or not. Arrow functions are also much more concise than full `functions` in many situations (though not this one)

Comment: @Thomas `const` is like `var` in that it declares a variable. However, that variable cannot be reassigned. the `() => {}` part is a function. It's the arrow function syntax (named after the `=>` part) and works basically like using `function() {}` but it's shorter. [There are few other differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/) but mostly irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a variable you could use an object with a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

```js
const obj = {
  a: 0,
  get b() { return this.a + 1 },
  set b(value) { this.a = value - 1 },
};

console.log(obj);
obj.a = 10;
console.log(obj);
obj.b = 20;
console.log(obj);
```

If you never plan to set `b`, then you can omit the setter.

Comment: Great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function for `b` instead and call it whenever is needed.

```
let a = 1;
const b = () => a + 1;
console.log(b()); // prints 2
a = 10;
console.log(b()); // prints 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to increment both the values.

```
const func= () => {
  a++;
  b++;
};
```

And then you can call the function each time you have to increment values. If you have to increment continuously for a fixed number of times then call the function inside a loop.