# For every 1 added to var1, add 1 to var2

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on an incremental game, [Gold Rush](https://squirrel-314.github.io), and am trying to create a total gold earned value that stores all of the gold the user has earned throughout the game, including the gold spent. So far I have put it so every time the player earns gold by clicking or incrementors it adds to the value. As the game gets more complex I find that this becomes harder to do, and I am trying to make a function that adds 1 to the totalGold variable every time it adds one to the gold variable. So far I have tried this:

```
if (gameData.gold + 1) {
   gameData.totalGold + 1;
}
```

The incrementor profits are gathered like this

```
function goldPerSecond() {
  return gameData.pickaxeGold + gameData.dwarfGold + gameData.gooseGold + gameData.mineGold + gameData.dragonGold + gameData.stoneGold + gameData.stationGold + gameData.leprechaunGold + gameData.sheepGold + gameData.rayGold + gameData.mergerGold;
}
```

And the clikcing profits gathered like this

```
function collectGold() {
  gameData.gold += gameData.clickinGold
  gameData.clicks += 1
  gameData.totalGold += gameData.clickinGold
}
```

I am fairly new to JavaScript and do not know any other way I could do it. It would be preferable if I did not have to use JQuery.
Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how you have structured your code, that if condition looks fairly good on its own. Can you add more code around it ?

Comment: This really sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would've placed this in a comment but I can't comment yet so here's what I think you should do.

As you said, adding to the total gold is tedious, so instead of that, create a function that adds gold, something like this

```
function addGold(gold) {
  gameData.gold = gameData.gold + gold;
  gameData.totalGold = gameData.totalGold + gold
}
```

So whenever you have to add gold you'll just say `addGold(1)` or replace `1` with whatever the number of gold you wanted to add, and the gold will be added to both the current gold and total gold

Comment: Happy to help. Also if you don't mind set this as the answer, so it won't remain unanswered

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a click event on each gold piece, when clicked, it should call a function that adds 1 to the total, and it should look like this:

```js
function addGold() {
  gameData.totalGold++; // Stands for: gameData.totalGold = gameData.totalGold + 1; (New Value = old value + 1)
}

// A click event for each gold piece, upon clicking, we call the `addGold` to increase the total
elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  addGold();
});
```

Not really sure if that's what you're looking for or I misunderstood you. A live demo on Codepen or JSBin or any alternative would be the best to help you!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could solve this problem is by registering a listener to the `gold` property, such that every time it were incremented, then `totalGold` property would be too. Here is an example of how it could work using vanilla JS:

```js
gameData = {
  goldInternal: 0,
  goldListener: function(val) {},
  totalGold: 0,
  set gold(val) {
    this.aInternal = val;
    this.goldListener();
  },
  get gold() {
    return this.goldInteral;
  },
  registerGoldListener: function(listener) {
    this.goldListener = listener;
  }
}

gameData.registerGoldListener(() => {
    gameData.totalGold += 1;
});

gameData.gold += 1;
console.log(gameData.totalGold);
gameData.gold += 1;
console.log(gameData.totalGold);
```

Please note that I referenced [this earlier SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript).