# How to handle a variable assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, handle

Let's say I have a variable

```js
let foo = {};
```

And I'm re-assigning it to something else.

```js
foo = {}
```

The question is **how do I know that the variable is re-assigned** ?

Like I've heard about Proxy, but it doesn't work

```js
// Creating a variable
let foo = {}

// Setting up a proxy
const fooProxy = new Proxy(foo, _ => {
  get: function(...) { ... },
  set: function(...) { ... }
}

// I just re-assigned the variable, and I want that `notify()` to tell me about it.
foo = {}

// I wanna call this function when the variable changes,  but it doesn't work 
function notify(){
  console.log("Dude, your variable has changed!");
```

Comment: Proxies work on objects, not variables.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to intercept variable assignment. You can use a proxy to catch modifications to the object.

Comment: It's not possible to get notified when a variable changes. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you explain what you're actual problem is that you try to solve via this we can probably give you an alternative solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe. No, it does not. I don't want to create a whole object with properties to change it.

Comment: Just do what mutation observers do but differently, they can monitor elements and changing document states why? Should help! A tip, it can deal with class introductory or lazily with Timeouts. I try to not use timers here for efficiency but if it's necessary you do it. Classes/Functions with callback functions on their change anytime you edit them.

This does come down to what you want to do and/or trying to secure with this "check-up"

Comment: @blanknamefornow Can you show an example of how I can  implement that ?

Answer (score -1):

There's a few examples but I guess it comes down to purpose? If means are to secure variables from changing, that likely won't happen but you can get as close with call-backs and promises/etc.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.skill = "novice";
  }
  setSkill(newSkill) {
    this.skill = newSkill;
    this.alertChange()
  }
  alertChange(){
    console.log(this.name+ " OH NO, My Skill!!!! No SECURITY HERE I GUESS?");
  }
}
let Test = new User("Donny");


Test.setSkill("Egg Champion");
```

```js
let test = undefined;
let test2 = undefined;
let watchvalue = 0;
function RepeatTillReady() {
  clearTimeout(test);
  clearTimeout(test2);

  test = setTimeout(()=>{
    if (watchvalue == 100) {
       console.log("That took a while but we made it!");
    } else {
      RepeatTillReady();
    }
  }, 200);
  
  test2 = setTimeout(()=>{
   watchvalue++;
  console.log("counting slowly now"+watchvalue);
  }, 100);
}
RepeatTillReady();
```

Here's another fun example when trying to catch DOM load in browsers! :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand anything. What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: Such is user-error then, perhaps you should read up more on what you're trying to do and explain better! Better luck next-time.