# How do I make an h1 that always has the text of the value of the variable "x"

Tags: javascript, html

So let's say I make a h1, ok?

I want to make it's value always set to... let's say "x".

How do I do this, I've tried with a while true loop, but that just crashes the site.

How is this doable, if it is?

[please don't give me dislikes for no reason, I'm just new here]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please add the code that you have tried.

Comment: Please be clear what do you want to achieve and what you've tried?

Comment: When you say `I make a h1` , Are you creating using JS or HTML?

Comment: I'm using HTML to make the h1

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the text of the h1 to be the value of the variable x

Comment: This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dL3ju458/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want your `H1` to always have the value as a variable in your JS. Even when the variable is changed.

For this, you might need certain restrictions on how you create the variable. This answer here [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript#answer-37403125) will be able to help you.

I've modified that a bit with more meaningful variables.

```
var watchableVariable = {
  originalVal: null,
  valListener: function(val) {},
  set val(val) {
    this.originalVal = val;
    this.valListener(val);
  },
  get val() {
    return this.originalVal;
  },
  registerListener: function(listener) {
    this.valListener = listener;
  }
}

watchableVariable.registerListener(function(val) {
  setH1Val(val);
});

var setH1Val = function(val){
    document.getElementById('the-title').innerText = val;
}

watchableVariable.val = 'Hey!';
setH1Val(watchableVariable.val)
setTimeout(function(){
    watchableVariable.val = 'Hello!';
}, 4000);
```

and the HTML

```
<h1 id="the-title"></h1>
```

Note: Even after this, there is a chance that someone might be able to change the text of the `h1` using other JavaScript methods. If you want to avoid that, you might want to look into `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to it https://jsfiddle.net/ramanay/9ngLyt6h/

Comment: I'm quite new to all of this, so it doesn't make sense yet to me. But thanks for providing a valid answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define `HTML` first and then `JS`, and no need to use `while(true)`. It will go forever, instead run once and replace it as it won't get change in the future.

```js
var x = "Text setted form JS - To this";

function myFunc() {
  document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = x;
  // or
  // document.getElementById("h1").textContent = x;
}
myFunc();
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">
  This should change to x forever
</h1>
```

**YOUR CODE AND MISTAKES**

```
<html>
<script> // DEFINING JS FIRST
  var x = ("To this")
  function myFunc() {
    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = x; //HERE document.getElementById("h1") will be null
  }
  while (true) { // INFINITE LOOP
    myFunc()
  }
</script>
<h1 id = "h1">
  This should change to x forever
</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand this, but I'm asking this if I were to change it in the future. What would I do then?

Comment: You need to do it with some kind of event then.

Comment: You can change the text with button `onclick` event

Comment: So there's no way to permanently set it, right?

Comment: If you are not changing it again then it is permanently set...

Answer (score 0):

on html : `<h1 id=solve>lorem</h1>`
on js : `var x = document.getElementById("solve").textContent;`
u can view it `console.log(x);`