# In javascript how can I run a command when the value of a variable changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerbi-embedded

I have an event listener that records the value of a toggle slicer in my application.  The toggle can have value set to OFF or ON.

I have a variable called filteredValue which contains the value of the current toggle state

```
   let filteredValue = state.filters[0].values;
```

I need to apply an action when the value of that variable changes.

eg

```
report.on('rendered', async () => {

//get all pages
  const pages = await report.getPages()

  //get active page
  let activePage = pages.filter(function(page) {
    return page.isActive
  })[0];

//get visuals on active page
  let visuals = await activePage.getVisuals();

//find target visual
  const TargetVisual = visuals.filter(function(visual) {
    return visual.name === "259fea6751434e7910b4" 
  })[0];

//get current state of visual 
  const state = await TargetVisual.getSlicerState();
  
  
//get current state value (on or off )
let filteredValue = state.filters[0].values


// DO SOMETHING HERE ONLY WHEN filteredValue CHANGES 

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listening for variable changes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

Comment: A better approach would be to add a `change` event handler to the toggle control in the DOM. Listening for a variable to change at runtime is not good practice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks - I guess I'm quite restricted.  The toggle control itself is managed in Power BI,  and the slicerState is the only available variable that gets surfaced.

Comment: In that case you possibly could use a [delegated event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)