# Can you make javascript realize something like a variable or element has changed?

Tags: javascript, events

```
<script>
  let y = 0
  let x = document.querySelector("p")
  setInterval(function(){y++; x.innerHTML = y},1000)
  x.addEventListener("change",change)
  function change(){console.log("i have changed")}

</script>
```

the script above is kind of what i'm looking for, this has worked for a input element, but i want a this kind of solution, however i am aware it might not be possible, thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the usage situation?

Comment: does this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript

Comment: It's possible for properties, but not for variables. For variables there is the [observer design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and the implementation [RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/).