# Inercept variable or property declaration

Tags: javascript

I want to intercept and log a statement, everytime a variable or property is declared

As an example after I following code:

```js
let name = "John";
let greet = function(personName) { 
    let greeting = 'hello';
    return greeting + ' ' + personName;
}
greet(name);
```

I should get following log:

```
name was created in window scope
greet was created in window scope
personName was created in greet scope
greeting was created in greet scope
```

Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: This is not a XY problem. This is exactly what I want to do. Thanks :)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if doing this required digging into the internals of the browser and JavaScript engine itself.  Why do you want to do this in the first place?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, you need to log it by checking it programmatically

Comment: Without modifying the engine, or altering the premises slightly, I'd say this isn't possible.

Comment: You can't get the event something is declared, but you can get the event when a property on an object changes, is deleted, iterated over, etc with [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve and how are you doing it? are you writing a test? how do you import the code file

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan I am trying to create a tree of scopes object. Where each object will have details of property declared

Comment: This might help what you are trying to do. I can't comment, [listening for var changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Is it also not possible by parsing the source code? IDEs know variable scope very well.

Comment: You can most definitely use a library like acorn or others which generates AST ([see here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/995133dc17bd5a73e24c5f1b3a5cce1e/b06b4d9f3315b0f7af21f7ecb286726ddd96526c)) which can then be programmatically analysed. But that's not what the question asked.

Comment: You have opened a whole new world to me good sir. This is almost exactly I was asking.

Comment: The only thing is, [here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/995133dc17bd5a73e24c5f1b3a5cce1e/f98a95bc37a1c41fb8b723d5f96f2fb09dad0dc5), how do I know name in L5 is the one declared in L4 and not the one in L1