# Trying to manipulate dom object in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate an existing DOM while playing around with building browser extensions and I can't seem to track down the correct process for one instance:

One of the pages I'm working with does a search call based on a field input.  I am trying to trigger this programmatically, but I cannot get it to work by changing the value or triggering a simple change event.

This is what the DOM element looks like:

```
<input aria-label="collectible search" class="Container_search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Here" value>
```

This is what I'm currently trying, which changes the text in the box, but doesn't trigger the event:

```
    var myInputElement =  document.querySelector('.Container_search-input');
    var myEventX = new Event("change", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
    myInputElement.setAttribute("value", 'search text');
    //myInputElement.value = 'search text';
    myInputElement.dispatchEvent(myEventX);
```

I've also tried the above changing the input instead of the value.  Nothing seems to trigger the event listener.

Is there something that may be adding an additional layer of abstraction here?  I think the page is being rendered using reactJS.

This is what I see for the first properties in Chrome's dev tools

```
value: ""
__reactEventHandlers$fq43xerpa7q: 
  aria-label: "collectible search"
  className: "Container_search-input"
  onChange: e=>C(e.target.value)
  length: 1
  name: "onChange"
  arguments: (...)
  caller: (...)
  [[FunctionLocation]] : <unknown>
    [[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
    apply: ƒ apply()
    arguments: (...)
    bind: ƒ bind()
    call: ƒ call()
    caller: (...)
    constructor: ƒ Function()
    length: 0
    name: ""
    toString: ƒ ()
    Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance): ƒ [Symbol.hasInstance]()
    get arguments: ƒ ()
    set arguments: ƒ ()
    get caller: ƒ ()
    set caller: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]: <unknown>
        [[Prototype]] : Object
        [[Scopes]] : Scopes[0]
        [[Scopes]] : Scopes[3]
        placeholder : "Search Here"
        type : "text"
        value : ""
        [[Prototype]] : Object
```

I can't copy all of the properties here, but there is also another that is a reactInternal Instance that might be relevant.

I'm not quite sure how else to approach this. Hours of internet searches continue to lead to examples only for editing from the page creator's perspective, which is not relevant to my problem.

Comment: Could it be that `var myInputElement =  document.querySelector('.Container_search-input');` has returned an array of elements and not just one? Do a `console.log(myInputElement)` straight after to see.

Comment: No, it is returning the correct (single element).  Have tested and confirmed via the console as well @jQueeny

Comment: Maybe this thread can provide answers: [listening for variable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Should the event be "input" instead of change?
var myEventX = new Event("change", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
--- updated solution ---
Try setTimeOut as it seems like the script fetches dom element before its rendered.
Working Example here - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactjs-playground-forked-c39rxl?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Comment: I have tried it both ways, and it does not seem to work either.

Comment: it would be easier to resolve if you could tell the expected output

Comment: Keith, see this implemntation it is getting dispatched.   https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactjs-playground-forked-c39rxl?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A15%2C1 if you are implementing on react, do you get any error?

Comment: @keith ^^ please look at the above implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue specific to **React**, as you may see in the below link from the Official React Repository. A contributor states the following:

> https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19389#issuecomment-660386187
>
> Hey @..., this is expected behavior. `onChange` will only fire when the
> value in the input has changed due to user input or some other DOM
> mutation on that input element. It isn't meant to fire when `value`
> changes.
>
> Hope that helps!

This would essentially work on other frameworks or Vanilla JS.

Comment: This is what I assume is the case. But is there no way to programmatically enter the value AND trigger the event?  I feel like there must be some way to do this given the browser is the medium that tells the react an input from the user has occurred.

Answer (score -1):

Hey If i understood the problem correctly, you want to trigger a function when there is change in text of search input.

I have made a fork of your code sandbox and tried to fix the issue. Let me know if that helps or if I am understanding it wrong.

[Code sand box link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactjs-playground-forked-4ck2qf?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A36%2C25)