I have a variable that I want the program to continuously check its value
I have a variable that I want the program to continuously check its value. the code goes something like this:
var score = 1

if (player touches the star) 
{
    player moves to bottom of screen
score = score + 1
}

if (score == 2)
{
   a bunch of images.x = 1300
`your text`}

this is obviously not the real code (i use javascript with phaser library) but i hope that you get the idea
i tried changing the place in the code where if (score == 2) { a lot of images move off screen} but it did not work. I even put the places where the images .x properties were mentioned inside if (score > 2) if statements but it did not move the images no matter what. I think that the only way to fix this is to constantly check the score variable.

sorry guys ignore the 'mytext' thing in the question

a very simmilar question was asked a few years ago on this website with the title JavaScript continuously check a variable but that only works for true or false variables it seems like

I believe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862441

Maybe you are talking about the “game loop”.

The easiest way to check a variable multiple time is as James mentiond in the game loop, the update function.
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create,
        update
    },
    // ...
}; 

function create () {
   // ...
}

function update () {
    //... this function is called 60 times per second
}
new Phaser.Game(config);

You just will have to becareful how to access the variables. Make the part of the object like this this.score = 2 or make the global variable. I would not recommend the later.
Update, based on comment:


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: { gravity: { y: 100 }},
    },
    scene: {
        create,
    },
}; 

function create () {
    let score = 0;
    let label = this.add.text(10,10, 'Score: 0')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let player = this.add.rectangle( 50, 10, 10, 10, 0xffffff );
    
    // adding a physics body to the GameObjects 
    this.physics.add.existing(player); 
    
    // create "Coins" GameObjects
    let coin1 = this.add.rectangle( 50, 50, 10, 10, 0xff0000 );
    let coin2 = this.add.rectangle( 50, 80, 10, 10, 0xff0000 );
    
    // adding a physics body to the GameObjects 
    this.physics.add.existing(coin1, true); 
    this.physics.add.existing(coin2, true); 
    
    // collider: callback function that checks if the player collides with coins
    // One could also use the function "overlap", if the player should not be slowed down, on collision
    this.physics.add.collider(player, [coin1, coin2], (p,c) =>{
        // remove coin
        c.destroy();
        // add score
        score += 2;
        // update label
        label.setText(`Score: ${score}`);
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




I understand that I must put this.score = 2 in the update function, but how would i put the function that is called when the player touches the star in the update function (it crashes when I do this).

@BilalSiddiqui It depends always on your usecase since there are many ways to do things in phaser. I updated my answer with a new code. Here I'm using the collider function, this one is only called when to objects collide. I could have done it with the update function, but in this usecase like this it is easier.  I hope this helps.
